# apply patch when asked `File to patch`, what should I do?

Tags: kernel, system-installation, patch

I have a system freeze issue and I found this [discusion](https://github.com/hadess/rtl8723bs/issues/33) on github, one of them suggest to add 5 patches:

> 

[image]

> 

When I type:

```
patch p1 < 0001-PM-autocomplet.patch
```

It asked `File to patch`, I don't know what to fill. How can I proceed and apply these patches. 
[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: Do you understand that patches apply to the kernel source code, which you then have to compile to produce a kernel image, which you then have to install properly on the intended target system and reboot into it? You can't just run `patch -p1 < patchfile` and reboot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To apply a patch of this form:

```
diff --git a/include/linux/pm_qos.h b/include/linux/pm_qos.h
index 0f65d36..ff59753 100644
--- a/include/linux/pm_qos.h
```

with `patch -p1`, several conditions have to be met.

1. You have to be in the top-level directory of a kernel source tree. The `-p1` option will strip one path component from the file names, so that `a/include/linux/pm_qos.h` will be treated as `include/linux/pm_qos.h`. This is a relative path which has to resolve from your current working directory.
2. The file `include/linux/pm_qos.h` has to exist in the version of the kernel that you're trying to patch.

If 1 and 2 are not met, then `patch` will not find the file to apply and interactively ask you to supply the path name.

Then of course:

3. The `include/linux/pm_qos.h` file has to be "sufficiently similar" to the one from which the patch was produced, otherwise the patch will fail to apply.

The same remarks apply separately to all other files that are mentioned in the patch.

If you're trying to patch a different version of the kernel from the one against which the patch was produced, I'm afraid you're "in over your head"; that requires some level of understanding of kernel development (depending on how complex are the adjustments required in the patch for it to apply).

Sometimes we find that kernel files have just been renamed; a patch will apply fairly cleanly if the files mentioned in it are renamed to the new names. On the opposite end, in the worst cases, you have to actually understand what the patch is doing (possibly by looking at the original kernel where it was made), and then implement the same logic from scratch in the target kernel.  In cases of "intermediate difficulty", you just have to deal with issues like variable names, function names and struct member names having been renamed; the patch will apply if it just follows new names.

Comment: I can't understand your explanation, too technical for me. All I want is to patch these patches to the current working kernel, is that possible?

Comment: If you're following someone's exact steps for patching and they don't work, then considerable technical skill is required to resolve that situation by yourself. From the information available about what went wrong, it is not possible to tell whether the patches can or cannot apply.

Comment: If you're confused by text like "you have to be in the top-level directory of a kernel source tree", then maybe get someone else to do this task.

Comment: These patches is for the a [wireless driver](https://github.com/hadess/rtl8723bs), the author says in the readme as if apply these patches is quite straightforward...

Comment: Yeah, that text I can't understand at all.

Comment: Can you please give a step by step patching, because after all I am installing the system... Therefore I don't mind whether it will break my system or not..

Comment: Although I would like to give you step by step instructions that will just work, it is simply not possible.

Comment: Why not possible? because you don't know my kernel version?

Comment: You're best off getting support from the author of the patch.